# run bash command in a script with a list of filenames

Tags: bash, arguments

I have to run a command that merges some files in every subdirectory for a directory using bash scripts.
The script finds all .ps files, changes them to a .png file and then merges .png files for a directory. This has to be done for all subdirectories.

2_treeimages: contains a list of directories.

For every directory in 2_treeimages
   convert .ps to png and then merge.

The following program converts the files to .png but gives an error while merging because the merging command expects a list of file names but this gives a single string.

```
ps_dir=2_treeimages
for dirname in "$ps_dir"/*
do
  inputlist=""
  for filename in "$dirname"/*
  do
    if [ ${filename: -3} == ".ps" ]
    then 
        filenoext="${filename%.*}"
        result="$filenoext.png"
        convert  "$filename" "$result"
        inputlist+="$result"
    fi  
  done  


  combined_image="$dirname.png"
  echo "$inputlist" 
  echo "$combined_image"
  convert -append "$inputlist"  "$combinedimage"

done
```

The inputlist is displayed as
'/2_treeimages/review12/review12sent0.png/2_treeimages/review12/review12sent1.png'

```
However it should be run as with 2 arguments
'/2_treeimages/review12/review12sent0.png'
'/2_treeimages/review12/review12sent1.png'
```

Comment: I guess you're missing a space when appending to `inputlist`, like: `inputlist+="$result "`

Comment: adding a space does not make a difference as it still considers it one argument. I think I should use an array but  not sure how to use it

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out how to use an array for it and it works now.
Here is what I did

```
    ps_dir=2_treeimages
    for dirname in "$ps_dir"/*
    do
       i=0 args=()
      for filename in "$dirname"/*
      do

        if [ ${filename: -3} == ".ps" ]
        then 
            filenoext="${filename%.*}"
            result="$filenoext.png"
            convert  "$filename" "$result"
            args[$i]="$result"
            ((++i))

        fi  
      done  


      combined_image="$dirname.png"
      convert  "${args[@]}" -append "$combined_image"

done
```